# Intranet Application best practice? ApplicationPoolIdentity or not?

Tags: c#, iis-7

I have a local Intranet application that does some file validation using Directory.Exists and File.Exists. Unfortunately, the checks fail due to the fact that the application is running as "ApplicationPoolIdentity" and that account doesn't have access to the UNC paths the Directory.Exists and File.Exists are checking.

Should I give that ApplicationPoolIdentity account permissions to read those directories? (All of the directories appear under a top level folder of a single server.) If so, how?

Or, should I run the Application Pool under a domain account and grant that account permissions? (If I do need to create a new account, what permissions should I give it?)

Thanks for any input!

Comment: Why do your apps need to check external directories and files?

Comment: Because this app contains a module for our CAD department to log their data files in and track them via versioning, etc. I want to make sure the path and filename they enter exists (to insure there isn't a typo).

Comment: It takes a while to update - you're all good now. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a rule I normally create a custom account, but if you want to grant additional rights to shares etc. I would say that it is the best option.

Create a new AppPool with a custom identity with the relevant access to the shares. Then have the application run under this new AppPool. That way you can have other applications that do not require access to the shares in AppPools that do not have this access.

If you are using Windows 7 or Window 2008 R2 you might want to look at [Virtual Accounts](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd548356%28WS.10%29.aspx).

Here is a good article on the topic of [Application Pool Identities](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/624/application-pool-identities/)

Comment: I do have it running under it's own App Pool. I just wasnt sure about what permissions I should give the account. Also, the selector says "ApplicationPoolIdentity" (Recommended) and I wasn't sure if it was wise to change it from that Identity.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set read ACLs for the following identity: IIS AppPool\. You can do it either from the folder properties dialog (if your computer is on the domain, make sure Locations is set to the local machine in the "Select Users or Groups" dialog) or using [icacls](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753525%28WS.10%29.aspx) from the command line.